#  how to send input to multiple emulated mice using dsf(device simulation framework)?

Tags: input, virtual, device-driver, wdk, multiple-mice

How do i send input to 4 different emulated mice? This is specific to dsf(device simulation framework). I would like to send an input report to the emulated usb mouse devices the script creates in generichid script in generichid samples folder under dsf.
Im just having trouble figuring out the hex or keycodes to send in the input report to tell the OS to move the mouse and simulate a left mouse click event.

Comment: I figured out the answer to this problem and the script is posted on http://kinectmultipoint.codeplex.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind its located on teh website under downloads section for more information. This code does not work yet though:
 ExtHubPort = ExtHub.Ports(1)
            ExtHubPort.HotPlug(GenericHIDDSFDev)

This is where i plug in the generic usb mouse device.

If someone wishs they can read the code above from link but i believe its an simple error somewhere i made that is causing this to happen.

I have a problem because the everything up to the Softhidreceiver i know works because ive been testing it.

Comment: But everything works the same as in vbscript except the emulated device driver install fails. If anyone finds an article on device simulation framework log files i can have this project completed this weeked.

Comment: I got the test vbscript to run using script control on 32-bit computers but still need 64-bi solution to problem.

Comment: I do know that their are classes with /s that can be used for multiple devices but I need to just figure out how to do that in code.

Comment: I have a vbscript file i execute from vb.net using script control for 32-bit computers at the address below so this is answered. Please check here at this link as i will provide no code samples here because of the length of them: http://kinectmultipoint.codeplex.com